# Would sharing memory across docker containers limit the overall memory usage? Is it possible on Windows?

Tags: docker, ram

The project I'm working on uses roughly 10 different docker containers for various services that communicate with each other. Each one uses a lot RAM and it's hard to limit our containers too much because we need to err on the side of caution and have extra for each one.

What I would like to do is share RAM across containers so that they have a shared pool and need less extra RAM for each one.

I see shared memory is possible with
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#ipc-settings---ipc

I'm not sure if this actually would solve this problem or if it's only useful for allowing containers to communicate with each other via named pipes kind of thing.

Also we're running Windows Docker containers on a Windows host and it looks like this might only be possible on a Linux host? The Linux host part of it is potentially fixable.

Comment: I'm not sure about sharing among containers, but you can "swap" memory from a container to the disk: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#limit-a-containers-access-to-memory